# LINQ query against GridView filled with SqlDataSource

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq, gridview

I need to make a `LINQ` query against `GridView` filled with `SqlDataSource` - to create a Dictionary from rows.

So I have:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridCurrency" DataSourceID="sourceCurrency" OnDataBound="gridCurrency_DataBound"
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sourceCurrency" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnStr %>" SelectCommand="[getCurrencies]" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" />
```

and

```
protected void gridCurrency_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dic = (from row in ((DataView)sourceCurrency.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)).Table.AsEnumerable()
              select new
              {
                  ID = (byte)row["ID"],
                  CurrencyName = (string)row["name"]
              }).ToDictionary(k => k.ID, k => k.CurrencyName);
}
```

Is there any better way then my to get a `DataTable` from `GridView` while no `GridView.DataSouce` is present.

Comment: I don't use SqlDataSource anymore, but back when I did, and I needed to get a DataTable in my code-behind, that's exactly how I did it.

Comment: @Byron Sommardahl: thanks! what do you use now?

Comment: Well, in order to have more control and to test properly, I bind my server controls to a dataset from code-behind. I'll post an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to bind my server controls in my code-behind. I can debug and test this better. I also don't have to do other crazy things to get to my bound data from code-behind... it's already there. Here's an example.

Assume the following stored proc in SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE selEmployees
@DeptId int,
@SearchString varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM Employees 
WHERE DeptId = @DeptId AND CONTAINS(*, SearchString);   
END
```

I can match that stored proc to a method in my entity class or page code-behind, like this:

```
public static DataSet selEmployees(int DeptId, string SearchString)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(clsData.getConnString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selEmployees", con); // stored proc name
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter _DeptId = cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeptId", SqlDbType.Int); //stored proc parameter name and datatype
        _DeptId.Value = DeptId; //assign method parameter value to sql parameter
        SqlParameter _SearchString = cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchString", SqlDbType.Int); //stored proc parameter name and datatype
        _SearchString.Value = SearchString; //assign method parameter value to sql parameter
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            adapt.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Then, I can just bind my data to my server control at page_load like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = Employees.selEmployees(MyDeptId, MySearchString);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

If you try this, be sure to remove the DataSourceId parameter from the GridView in your mark-up. DataSource and DataSourceId don't play nice together.

Note: There are actually a million better ways to do this. The aim of this post was to illustrate one easy alternative to using SqlDataSource in your mark-up.

One way to take this a step futher is to assign the resultant dataset to a re-usable variable like a page property:

```
public partial class ViewEmployees : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public DataSet DataSetEmployees { get; set; } //re-usable property gets set at page_load

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //save the dataset to a re-usable property
            DataSetEmployees = Employees.selEmployees(MyDeptId, MySearchString);

            //bind using the property
            GridView1.DataSource = DataSetEmployees;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

With that simple upgrade, you have the ability to use and re-use the DataSet throughout the page without having to re-query the database.

Comment: @Byron Sommardahl: Thanks so much! Very interesting. And fresh. And next step could you recommend? I mean you phrase 'There are actually a million better ways to do this'.

Comment: I feel like the next step would be to become more object oriented in your thinking. In my own progression, I have moved away from JUST working with datasets to working with generic lists and objects. So, instead of a set of rows of customers, I have a strongly-typed list of customer objects.

Comment: One way to move in that direction is to try Linq to SQL classes (google that). Once you've mastered that, you could move on to Entity Framework (or whatever is "in style" at the time). Someone might have some better suggestions.